# Pushing objects to an array, then modifying them, makes all object properties the same

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

When I run this code:

```js
var e = {
  'id': 0,
  'name': 'n'
};
var data = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  e.id = i;
  data.push(e);
}

console.log(data);
```

I expect `data` to look like this:

```
[
  {
    'id': 0,
    'name': 'n'
  },
  {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'n'
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'n'
  }
]
```

but the actual result is:

```
[
  {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'n'
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'n'
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'n'
  }
]
```

Why does this happen and how to fix this?

Comment: JavaScript never copies composite data structures on assignment. You're pushing a reference to the object into the array.

Comment: I know. How it may be solved ?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you've pushing the same object multiple times and editing it.

Try defining e inside the loop:

```
var data=[];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    var e={'id':i,'name':'n'};
    data.push(e);
}
```

Or with cloning (uses jquery):

```
var data=[];
var e={'id':0,'name':'n'};
for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    var e_copy = jQuery.extend({}, e); // or clone(e)
    e_copy.id=i;
    data.push(e);
}
```

Roll your own cloning fn:

```
function clone(o){
    var o_copy = {}; 
    for (var p in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(p)){
            o_copy[p] = o[p]
        }
    }
    return o_copy;
}
```

Comment: I can't. I should use external variable "e".

Comment: moreover: assignment
"e" to any local var has make same result

Comment: jQuery? Why jQuery? `var e_copy = {}; for (var p in e) e_copy[p] = e[p];`

Comment: Clone !
It's enough for me. 
Thanks!

Comment: @squint jquery has a helpful cloning fn. You could use the one in underscore or roll your own. I'm just more familiar with that one

Comment: Just seems like overkill to suggest any library to replace a handful of characters.

Comment: @squint I've added your clone fn too :)

Comment: pure JS clone is even better, thanx!

Comment: @AlexanderC better thank squint